# Pentaho kettle convert date to unix

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to pacha a string format dated `"2019-05-14 13:30:00"` to a UNIX format.

In javascript I got it but in the javascript kettle module I am not able to return the numeric value `1557833442`

the line of code is this:

```
const tests = (new Date ("2019-05-14 13:30:00"). getTime () / 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Date() constructor doesn't like the format you are using.

If you want the current date, use a **Get System Info**, it has a number of useful date options.

If you are converting an incoming field, use the **Select Values** step to change the metadata, using the format string that matches your string field's format.